# How to keep the values of a column unchanged whether the values of other column are deleted?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want any value written in cell `A1` to be shown in cell `B1`. For this, I am using the formula `=A1` in cell `B1`.  Similarly, to show the content of cell `A2`, I applied `=A2` formula in `B2` and the same formula is dragged into entire column `B`.

But here the problem is when I delete the content of column `A` then the content of column `B` is deleted automatically.  So I want a formula which should keep the content of column `B` even in the situation where the content of column `A` is deleted.

I know this can be done by simply copying all values of column `A` and then pasting them into column `B`.  I want a formula to do so.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a formula instead of VBA because coding disables the undo and redo utility of Excel. A snapshot of the excel sheet:

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using copy and paste or a VBA script to do this for you, it's not possible.

You could turn off auto-calculation of formulas, but this would prevent all formulas from working and new cells wouldn't update either.

The point of using a formula to do things is that they will recalculate and update to calculate for you when required. Otherwise, you may as well be hard coding the entire sheet.

You *can* replace the formulas with their calculated values, but really you may as well be copy and pasting the entire column for something this simple. Instructions to replace formulas can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-a-formula-with-its-result-38001951-c0e8-4fbd-9048-37ef81e2891e#bmreplace_a_formula_with_its_calculated)

> 1. Select the cell or range of cells that contains the formulas.
> 2. Click Copy
> 3. Click Paste Button image.
> 4. Click the arrow next to Paste Options Button image, and then click Values Only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [iterative calculation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4#bmchange_the_number_of_times_microsoft_). Enable iterative calculation by going to Options -> Formulas and checking the "Enable Iterative Calculation" box. Then use this formula in column B:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1)
```

Comment: This gives me an excel warning of `Circular References` when I deleted the content in column `A`. May not be a good idea to have circular references in ones file. Agreed that the formula does its job